# While loop creates never ending input loop

Tags: java, loops, input, while-loop, nested-loops

So I want my program to read the inputs "A" "B" or "C" and display the number of each by displaying asterisks. But I am running into an issue where it never reads and displays my input.

My code is as follows:

```
if (command == 'A'){
    System.out.println("Type the additional input in a single line.");
    while(in.hasNext()){
        String input = in.next().toUpperCase();
        if(input.equals("A")){ numA++;}
        if(input.equals("B")){ numB++;}
        if(input.equals("C")){ numC++;}
    }
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("\n%4s      |", "A");
    for (int a = 1; a <= numA; a++) { 
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("\n%4s      |", "B");
    for (int b = 1; b <= numB; b++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("\n%4s      |", "C");
    for (int c = 1; c <= numC; c++) { 
        System.out.print("*");}
        System.out.println();
        double gpa = ((numA*4)+(numB*3)+(numC*2)) / ((numA+numB+numC));
        System.out.println("GPA: " + gpa);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    }
```

Comment: What is `in` exactly - an InputStreamReader? A Scanner? I'd guess it's relevant here if you're saying that's what's not working.

Comment: Sorry, yeah "in" is the name for the Scanner.

Comment: Could you please put `in` declaration and instantiation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Realized I was missing a break statement. My teacher wanted the data to be displayed after the input of any number. The break statement was something I had never learned about or used before but here is how i fixed it for those who are interested:

```
 if (command == 'A') {                                                               
     System.out.println("Type the additional input in a single line.");              
     while (in.hasNext()) {                                                          
         String input = in.next().toUpperCase();                                     
         if (input.equals("A")) {                                                    
             numA++;                                                                 
         }                                                                           
         if (input.equals("B")) {                                                    
             numB++;                                                                 
         }                                                                           
         if (input.equals("C")) {                                                    
             numC++;                                                                 
         }                                                                           
         if (input.compareTo("A") < 0 || input.compareTo("Z") > 0)                   
             break;                                                                  

     }                                                                               
     System.out.println("---------------------------------------");                  
     System.out.printf("\n%4s      |", "A");                                         
     for (int a = 1; a <= numA; a++) {                                               
         System.out.print("*");                                                      
     }                                                                               
     System.out.println();                                                           
     System.out.printf("\n%4s      |", "B");                                         
     for (int b = 1; b <= numB; b++) {                                               
         System.out.print("*");                                                      
     }                                                                               
     System.out.println();                                                           
     System.out.printf("\n%4s      |", "C");                                         
     for (int c = 1; c <= numC; c++) {                                               
         System.out.print("*");                                                      
     }                                                                               
     System.out.println();                                                           
     double gpa = ((numA * 4) + (numB * 3) + (numC * 2)) / ((numA + numB + numC));   
     System.out.println("GPA: " + gpa);                                              
     System.out.println();                                                           
     System.out.println("---------------------------------------");                  
 }
```

Sorry for the dumb question, I'm brand new to java.